# エフェメラルポートを使用する理由を教えてください

Tags: aws

### 疑問点

ポート80でwebサーバーを実行するインスタンスにロードバランサーがアクセスする場合のインバウンド、アウトバウンドルールについて質問です。
適切なルールは以下になるかと思います。

ロードバランサーのサブネットが仮に10.0.0.0/24とします。

- インバウンドルール　ポート80 送信元：10.0.0.0/24
- アウトバウンドルール　ポート1024~65535 送信先：10.0.0.0/24

このうちアウトバウンドルールでなぜエフェメラルポートを使用するのでしょうか？
ポート80で入ったので同じ80で出てロードバランサーのサブネットにアクセスするルールで良いのではないかと思いました。

### 質問

エフェメラルポートそのものの解釈が間違っていないか等ご指摘・ご教示願います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問の前提としていくつか欠けていますが、それこそが疑問点の原因だと思いますので、回答というよりは欠けている部分を説明します。

> ポート80でwebサーバーを実行するインスタンスにロードバランサーがアクセスする

をしっかりと理解してください。通信には送信元と送信先があります。

- 送信元： ロードバランサー

  - IPアドレス： **不定**（サブネットが仮に10.0.0.0/24、そのうちの１つ）
  - ポート番号： **1024～65535**（エフェメラルポート）
- 送信先： webサーバー

  - IPアドレス： **不明**（質問文で言及されず）
  - ポート番号： **80**（webサーバーなので）

この通信を許可するルールを作成することになります。

質問文で求められている「ルール」というのも不明確で

- NetworkACL

  - サブネットを流れる通信のルール

    - **インバウンド・アウトバウンド関係なく双方の通信を許可する**
- セキュリティグループ

  - ロードバランサーのルール

    - ロードバランサーにとっては**アウトバウンドルール**
  - webサーバーのルール

    - webサーバーにとっては**インバウンドルール**

といくつかあり、それぞれの立場で設定すべき内容も異なってきます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！そもそもの理解が浅かったのでご指摘いただけて理解できました！Webサーバに接続するまでの流れとポート番号がごちゃごちゃになっていたのでスッキリしました。